# How to hide a tooltip with a javascript if statement?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a tooltip that appears with all the text in my word tree and now I want to hide it from 5 categories with a javascript if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If the tooltip is because of title attribute and not something custom made then you can just remove title attribute with below line

**$('.targetElement').removeAttr('title');**

on the other hand, if the tooltips are custom created then you'll need to handle mouse-hover event and check if it has to be hidden then hide it